# Using text2vec in R - Error: no package called ‘futile.options’

Tags: r, text2vec

I successfully installed `text2vec` in R, but when I try to load it with `library(text2vec)`, I'm getting an error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘text2vec’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
there is no package called ‘futile.options’
```

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise - version 1709. Build: 16299.726

And my R details are:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.1                         
year           2018                        
month          07                          
day            02                          
svn rev        74947                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the futile.options package installed.
Try:
`install.packages("futile.options")`

You can then confirm the package is installed with:
`"futile.options" %in% as.data.frame(installed.packages())$Package`

Comment: Worked. Cheers!

Comment: @Kallikrates If this answered your question,  please upvote the answer and accept it.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)